# SOH (Start of Heading) in XML / XSLT

Tags: xml, parsing

I'm trying to create the SOH (Start Of Heading) character in XML 1.1 using XSLT. 
I need this character to delimitter two strings.

I tried the following strings, but in most cases the parser dont't accept them.

```
&#x1;
&#33;
#x1
&#x61;
```

Onlye the second one was accepted, but this is just a `!`.

Did anyone know how to add the SOH correctly to the XML?

Thanks alot... 
SoniX

Comment: Only [XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets) parsers accept that character  . You need an XSLT processor that use an XML 1.1 parser. I think you can configure Saxon for that. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#introduction) _"Definition: A transformation in the XSLT language is expressed in the form of a stylesheet, whose syntax is well-formed XML [ [XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#REC-xml) ] conforming to the Namespaces in XML Recommendation [ [Namespaces in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#REC-xml-names) ]."_

Answer (score 1):

SOH = `^A` = Decimal `1` = Hex `01`

Try `&X01` or `&01`

IHTH

Comment: Thanks for your help. adding one of your tries in xslt i got an error that the entity was referenced, but not decladed. Btw, of course i will mark the answer.. ;-) thx!